# draw simple vectors with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, draw

Good evening everyone. 
I'm trying to learn how to deal with drawing packages in Latex but all I found on the web is too complicated for what I need to do. I guess if anyone of you can help me. basically I need to draw 6 vectors and giving names to them and to the angles. I can attach an image of what I need to realize. 
Can someone help me with a code which realize this, in order that I can then study it to better understand how things work?

[image]

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Do you have some code? Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You will find here many examples, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164162/124842

Comment: Hi, you can see too this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267201/tikz-angle-between-two-vectors-and-a-projection.

Comment: The first and third example of the pgf/tikz manual walk you through making pictures like these in great detail, page 29 onward. Don't worry about the length of the manual, you only need the first couple of pages. Manual can be found here: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 6):

as starting point (not reproduce your sketch, but on this basis you can see how to draw yours):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
phasor/.style = {very thick,-{Stealth}},
angles/.style = {draw, <->, angle eccentricity=1,
                 right, angle radius=7mm}
                        ]
% coordinates
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (x) node[below left] {$\mathit{Re}$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[below left] (y) {$\mathit{Im}$};
% phasors
    \draw[phasor] (0,0) -- (300:1.5) coordinate (i)  node[right] {I};% used polar coordinates
    \draw[phasor] (0,0) -- ( 30:2.5) coordinate (v)  node[right] {V};% used polar coordinates
% angles drawn by pic
\coordinate (X)   at (0,0);
\draw
    pic["$\theta=\phi-\SI{90}{\degree}$",angles] {angle=i--X--x}
    pic["$\phi$",angles] {angle=x--X--v}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]