# How can I make 3D drawing in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

Is there a way to make tikz draw in 3D, I am trying to draw vectors and axis in `$ \mathbb{R}^3 $` (in the space), maybe not one that advanced since I am new at using latex.

this is a try for the axis:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw [-latex](0,0)--(8,4);
  \draw [-latex](0,0)--(-4,-2);
  \draw (9,4.5) node {X};
  \draw [-latex](0,0)--(0,7);
  \draw (0,7.5) node {Y};
  \draw [-latex](0,0)--(8,-4);
  \draw (9,-4.5) node {Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it is really inconvenient to draw vectors in there since its 2D, I have to calculate with perspective.

the specific problem i try to solve is to draw the position vector of a line, the line and (if it is possible) a plane that contains the line and is perpendicular to the vector, but the first two are my main objectives.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: hi i will edit it, one question how can i use math mode in here, in the math stack exchange it work using $ but in here it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `tikz-3dplot` is one way to start. The `perspective` library is another one.

Comment: i can't add a new tag , can you do it?

Comment: @FranciscaAguayo [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths) meta post explains the rational behind not being able to render LaTeX (actually mathsJaX) here. As for helping with your problem can you be more specific. For example are there particular vectors you are trying to draw?

Comment: may be try to look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164155/2d-and-3d-vectors-in-tikz

Comment: thanks i will look it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy to understand what you are asking. Here is one way to use "3D" (coordinates given by three numbers).

Original code:

[image: 3D Axis]

New code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.8cm,0.4cm)}, y={(0cm,0.7cm)}, z={(0.8cm,-0.4cm)}]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0);
\draw (11,0,0) node{X};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (-5,0,0);
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,10,0);
\draw (0,11,0) node{Y};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,10);
\draw (0,0,11) node{Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Same 3D axis]

`x={(0.8cm,0.4cm)}, y={(0cm,0.7cm)}, z={(0.8cm,-0.4cm)}` is only needed because of the non-standard orientation of the axis.

Comment: i can't vote yet but this is really helpful for the orientation of the axis, Thanks!